# How to activate table preview menu in Bigquery Console?

Tags: google-bigquery

I started BigQuery trial account just before
and created sample table using a source with Drive URI & CSV.

When I clicked my uploaded table, it shows table information like schema and details.

I remember that there was a `preview` menu but I can't find it now. [image]

Is there anyway to activate table preview menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your table is created from a file from Google Drive, by default "Preview" tab is not available since it is considered as an [external table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-tables). I tested it to verify the behavior.

**Created table sourcing from Google Drive:**

[image]

What I could suggest is to load your data from Google Drive to BigQuery, so the "Preview" tab will be available. Also if you load your data in BigQuery, running queries will be faster compared from querying the table externally.

Comment: ooh i could find preview menu when i use GCS.case closed! thank you ricco.